# How to ensure that wireless Logitech keyboard is encrypted?

Tags: wireless, keyboard, encryption, logitech

Just as the title says, I'm using a wireless Logitech keyboard, and I want to ensure that my keystrokes are in fact encrypted. On Windows, I could do that very easily by using the Logitech SetPoint software, pressing a key sequence (Ctrl+Alt+F12), pressing the Connect button on the keyboard, and typing in an encryption key that's displayed on the monitor. Set and done!

How do I do the same on Ubuntu Linux?

Here is a screentorial on Windows:

[image: a]
[image: b]
[image: c]
[image: d]
[image: e]
[image: f]
[image: g]
[image: h]

Comment: I guess one either has to use wired keyboards on Linux or not give a damn about wireless security of keystrokes. Oh well, that will have to do...

Answer (score 6):

There is a graphical tool called Solar. It can also show many details of logitech devices. If it shows you an unencrypted connection, you can (if your keyboard is supported) use it to pair them properly.

Please check first if your keyboard is supported. There is a list and instructions on the website. Generally, Solar supports all unifying reciever devices and some of the others.

https://pwr.github.io/Solaar/

Comment: Still working great with ubuntu 20.04 and a recent logitech keyboard/mouse combo. New link: https://github.com/pwr-Solaar/Solaar. I did have to install it from their custom ppa rather than the default ubuntu repo because the version was out-of-date and not working with my device (v1.0.1 vs v1.0.3). Good news for me: the keyboard connection was already encrypted.

Answer (score 2):

Go through the pdf document , you will understand how a wireless keyboard works and what all security feature are built to the wireless devices to avoid eavesdropping.

http://www.blackhat.com/presentations/bh-dc-08/Moser/Whitepaper/bh-dc-08-moser-WP.pdf

And about the encryption software logitech setpoint , when checked there's no support provided by the logitech to my knowledge, but as a alternate you can  use a [HIDPoint](http://www.hidpoint.com/hidpoint/download/hidpoint.html) (freeware).

Answer (score 0):

> I guess one either has to use wired keyboards on Linux or not give a damn about wireless security of keystrokes.

You're heading in the wrong direction. I remember this feature from older keyboards I used during the 2000s and I thought this didn't survive the migration to Sepoint, I'm surprised to see that it did. (I also remember issues with older Logitech drivers in conjunction with Creative soundcards on Windows and each company blaming the other in their respective forums, gotta love those *constructive* days.) Anyways who claimed that this encryption from the late 90s or early 2000s is state of the art and secure?

If you worry about security look at the current state of the art: Logitech's unifying technology and Bluetooth starting with 2.1 seems to be safe, but encryption on some older Microsoft devices has been cracked.